# Please recommend some classical books or articles on the compressible Euler equations !

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Please recommend some classical books or articles on the local well-posedness result of compressible Euler equations ! The main aim is that I want to learn some basic methods and techniques about the local existence theory of quasilinear hyperbolic system. Eventually, I can apply the tools I mastered to solve the Euler-Poisson system (Of course, I need to the help of some classical articles). ^-^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By far, the ever best written book on the subject is that of Constantin Dafermos: *Hyperbolic Conservation Law in Continuum Physics*. Grundlehren der Mathematischen Wissenschaften **325**, Springer Verlag.

**Edit**. Of course, if you are already a bit familiar with the topic, you may have a look to the book by S. Benzoni-Gavage and I: *Multi-dimensional hyperbolic partial differential equations. First order systems and applications.* Oxford University Press (2007).

Comment: @Denis Serre: Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: I am reading Benzon-Gavage and Serre. I have not reached the Euler stuff yet but the book is superb!